# How to select multiple columns while keeping one of them distinct

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to select two columns (A & B) from a table and only keep the distinct values of one of them (A). However single value of A can map to multiple values of B. So the following query won't work

```
select distinct A, B from table1
```

I am thinking of something like this:

```
select A, agg(B) from table1 group by A
```

I want the `agg` function to just randomly pick a single value from B while grouping A. How to do it in Postgres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an *arbitrary* value ("any old value"), then `min()` and `max()` are arbitrary values:

```
select a, min(b) as b
from table1
group by a;
```

If you want an *indeterminate* value ("value from any row that matches"), then:

```
select distinct on (a) a, b
from table1
order by a;
```

If you want a *random* value ("value from a random matching row chosen from a uniform distribution"), then:

```
select distinct on (a) a, b
from table1
order by a, random();
```

In other words, the definition of "random" is different from "arbitrary" and "indeterminate".  However, `distinct on` is probably what you want along.

Comment: The answer of @Barbaros Özhan fits better with the question

Comment: @JaimeDrq . . . The question is:  "I want the agg function to just randomly pick a single value from B while grouping A."  The answer to that question is *not* a string aggregation.  In fact, if the OP wanted all the values, an array aggregation would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Use [*string_agg*](https://coderwall.com/p/eyknwa/postgres-group_concat) with comma :

```
select A, string_agg(distinct B,',') from table1 group by A;
```